# Showing ToastAndroid when app is closed with react-native and Headless JS

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to integrate BroadcastReceiver with my react-native app. I want to show the ToastAndroid whenever someone calls me. It works great when the app is running (either in foreground and background) but when I kill the app it doesn't trigger ToastAndroid anymore.

I've seen a video ([YT link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlzfcqDlovg)) of someone doing it in native code and it works even when the app is killed.

How can I accomplish it with react-native?

My Service code:

```
public class CallService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
@Override
protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "Call",
            Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
            5000,
            true
            );
    }
return null;
}
}
```

My Receiver code:

```
public final class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, CallService.class);

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
        String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra("state");
        if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");
            callIntent.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
        } 
    }

    context.startService(callIntent);
    HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
}
}
```

And JS code:

```
const Call = async (data) => {
  console.log('It works!', data);
  ToastAndroid.show('TEST ' + data.number, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
};
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('Call', () => Call);
```

Comment: Check out this library https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions

Comment: Description of the library says "Schedule a background job that will run your JavaScript when your app is in the background or foreground.". I'm looking for something that could run in the background even if app is closed (not running at all - you can see this behaviour at the end of video I linked).

Comment: What do you mean by "killing" the app? Force closing it in Settings? Please note that if the app is killed forcibly, it won't receive any broadcasts unless started again manually.

Comment: @Balhut Kindly refer to the link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25894. Hope this helps!

Comment: @K.Raj. Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!